# How to go back to the status of a commit of a repository in git?

Tags: git, github, git-commit

For instance, I got a link:

```
https://github.com/git/git/tree/e83c5163316f89bfbde7d9ab23ca2e25604af290
```

that Github page lists all the files of the repo in the specific commit, but it has no branch or tag, how can I use something like `git checkout ...` to switch to the status so I can view all the files in my code editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly what you suggested, with the commit ID

```
git checkout e83c5163316f89bfbde7d9ab23ca2e25604af290
```

That creates a "detached head" meaning you have checked out the files but are not on a branch, so can't commit changes to it. That's fine if you just want to examine the files and not make changes, when you're finished just go back to a known branch e.g. `git checkout master`

To create your own branch from that commit do this instead:

```
git checkout -b new_branch_name e83c5163316f89bfbde7d9ab23ca2e25604af290
```

Or equivalently

```
git branch new_branch_name e83c5163316f89bfbde7d9ab23ca2e25604af290
git checkout new_branch_name
```

Comment: Only the first seven number of the commit ID(e83c516) is needed, right??

Comment: Only as much as needed to disambiguate it, sometimes 4 is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can go `git checkout e83c5163316f89bfbde7d9ab23ca2e25604af290` but make sure you have the commit in your local repo.

Comment: If you would like a more detailed answer you can find one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-to-a-previous-git-commit)

Comment: You don't need to be "on the same branch" you just need to have that commit in your local repo, which can be done with `git fetch origin` (assuming `origin` is the github remote)

Comment: Cool - thanks for the correction @JonathanWakely - correction made.